# Subsumption in polymorphic types

Tags: haskell, types, ml

In [‘Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types’](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/putting.pdf), the authors talk about *subsumption*:

[image: 3.3 Subsumption]

I try to test things in GHCi as I read, but even though `g k2` is meant to typecheck, it doesn't when I try with GHC 7.8.3:

```
λ> :set -XRankNTypes
λ> let g :: ((forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int) -> Int; g = undefined
λ> let k1 :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int; k1 = undefined
λ> let k2 :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int; k2 = undefined
λ> :t g k1

<interactive>:1:3: Warning:
    Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type forall a1. a1 -> a1 at <interactive>:1:3
    Expected type: (forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int
      Actual type: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int
    In the first argument of ‘g’, namely ‘k1’
    In the expression: g k1
g k1 :: Int
λ> :t g k2

<interactive>:1:3: Warning:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Int] -> [Int]’ with ‘forall b. [b] -> [b]’
    Expected type: (forall b. [b] -> [b]) -> Int
      Actual type: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int
    In the first argument of ‘g’, namely ‘k2’
    In the expression: g k2
g k2 :: Int
```

I haven't really gotten to the point where I understand the paper, yet, but still, I worry that I have misunderstood something. Should this typecheck? Are my Haskell types wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The typechecker [doesn't know when to apply the subsumption rule.](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~forressa/academic/cas743-presentation.pdf)

You can tell it when with the following function.

```
Prelude> let u :: ((f a -> f a) -> c) -> ((forall b. f b -> f b) -> c); u f n = f n
```

This says, given a function from a transformation for a specific type, we can make a function from a natural transformation `forall b. f b -> f b`.

We can then try it successfully on the second example.

```
Prelude> :t g (u k2)
g (u k2) :: Int
```

The first example now gives a more informative error as well.

```
Prelude> :t g (u k1)
    Couldn't match type `forall a. a -> a' with `[a0] -> [a0]'
    Expected type: ([a0] -> [a0]) -> Int
      Actual type: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int
    In the first argument of `u', namely `k1'
    In the first argument of `g', namely `(u k1)'
```

I don't know if we can write a more general version of `u`; we'd need a constraint-level notion of less polymorphic to write something like `let s :: (a :<: b) => (a -> c) -> (b -> c); s f x = f x`

Comment: This is a great example of Haskell not taking its own notion of subtyping seriously... But it's generally not so bad to be a little more explicit when you need it.

Comment: GHC, you disappoint me. I was so sure GHC got this right I even glossed over my stupid mistake in my deleted answer here.

Comment: The type checker as described in the paper **does** know when to apply the subsumtion rule. It's apparently just GHC. I know this because I implemented the type checker described in that paper in Frege, and the Frege typechecker accepts `g k2` without complaints. (See here for an example: https://github.com/Frege/frege/issues/80#issuecomment-62257574)